# Update the item lists of other comboboxes after one combobox/textbox changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, system.reactive

I have a WinForms form which has a gridview and several comboboxes and textboxes. These comboboxes and textboxes are used to filter the data showing in the gridview.

The `Combobox1` list all distinct values in `Column1`, `Combobox2` list all distinct values in `Column2`, and so on, of the gridview.

How to implement the following function?

After `ComboboxN` (or a textbox) changed, it will not only filter the gridview (`select (first page)... from ... where Column1 = {Combobox selected value}`), but also refresh the item lists of all other comboboxes. The problem is

- The comboboxes lost it's current selected value after the item list is reassigned, and resetting the selected value will trigger updating other comboboxes's item lists and it will create infinity loop?

Will Rx framework be better tool to implement it?

Comment: What kind of filter you're applying? Can you post the code? I believe data binding can help a lot here.

Comment: It will dynamically create an SQL statement and get the first page of the big datasource and reset the gridview data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `ActiveControl` property if the `ActiveControl` is different then current event control then it should not be reassign the list back.

For example you have two comboboxes Combobox1 and Combobox2. Now, you want to populate combobox from one to another.

```
private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.ActiveControl != combobox2)
       FillCombobox2()
}
private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.ActiveControl != combobox1)
       FillCombobox1()
}
```

This is the first method that you can try.

But, I have a question here why are you doing like this. If the Combobox1 value is selected then Combobox2 should be repopulated. But, why are you repopulating Combobox1 again on Combobox2 value change?

BTW, if you want to set back the selected value in the other combobox after populating. then you can hold the previous selected value in any variable then you can set back after populating

```
var val = combobox2.SelectedValue;
FillCombobox2();
combobox2.SelectedValue = val;
```

You can avoid loop by checking `ActiveControl` as I have suggested above.